# Replace and transclude in link section of directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have a directive that needs to conditionally replace the node on which it is placed; sometimes it replaces it, sometimes it leaves it as it is.

This is what I do in the non-replace situation:

```
transclude(scope, function(clone){
            element.append(clone);
        });
```

And that works fine.

I would like to be able to put it on a node that it would replace with a template, transcluding it. How would I do that?

The following nearly seems to work:

```
 var node= angular.element('<a href="" role="button"></a>');

 transclude(scope, function(clone){                
   node.append(clone);
   element.replaceWith($compile(node)(scope))
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `outerHTML` to replace:

```
element[0].outerHTML = '<a href="" role="button"></a>';
```

and compile this template to transclude it.

**References**

- [AngularJS source: jqLiteSpec.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/jqLiteSpec.js)